# Restrict traffic using only Javascript

Tags: javascript, paypal, traffic

OK so I have a thank you page with a download button. This page is set as the thank you page for a buy now button in PayPal.

I want to restrict traffic so that the page is only accessible if you got there by being redirected from PayPal. So basically I want only allow traffic to this page where the referrer is PayPal.com

This would be easy in PHP, but due to the software I'm using I'm restricted to only using JavaScript. Can this be done?

Comment: Can you post the code of your attempt at solving this? Be mindful too that this will not be a _fool proof_ solution. For instance, if I disable JavaScript, I'll still get to the page...

Comment: I assume that your objective is to restrict access to the link/action behind download button, is it correct?

Comment: you should invert the flow control so that it still hides without javascript. name the page with a download button something that is the result of an operation on the referrer, like `paypal.com.html`, then use that operation on `document.referrer` and redirect them to the resulting page. that way, without knowing the specific referrer, one cannot get to the thank you page just by disabling JS or spotting the URL in view-source.

Comment: I may have to go with a different option and use PHP. I definitely want to protect this page and limit funny business.

Comment: @DanHenry, you told that you are "restricted to only using JavaScript". Does `document.referrer` fit you?

Answer (score 0):

You can't explicitly restrict a user from accessing the page via Javascript but you can make it rather difficult by using [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer).

Place this at the top of the `head`:

```
if (document.referrer.indexOf('paypal.com') >= 0) {
  // You could send them back with window.back()
  // or crash the page by throwing an error
}
```

Comment: note: not all browsers and/or preference settings allow for referrer passing.